# Netty - Best way to transmit strings with line breaks?

Tags: java, netty, decode, encode

I am working on a protocol that uses a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder for decoding, that splits the bytebuf whenever a line break is received.

Unfortunately, there must be the possibility to transmit strings with line breaks. By now the line breaks in the strings are read by the decoder and frames are created accordingly.

My idea is to encode those strings with Base64 and decode them after the framedecoder has done its work. My question is now, is there a better solution to this problem? Base64 brings overhead as well as additional encoding/decoding work.

Using another delimiter is not possible because i need it for the header fields of my protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NUL` delimiter based frame decoder and encoder for this in your pipeline. The delimiter documentation is [here](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/Delimiters.html#nulDelimiter()). For e.g in the decoder pipeline add the following.

```
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
```

same should be used while encoding for e.g.

```
@Sharable
public class NulEncoder extends OneToOneEncoder {

@Override
protected Object encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel,
        Object msg) throws Exception {
    ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer((ChannelBuffer)msg, Delimiters.nulDelimiter());
    return buffer;
}
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! I came up with another solution in the meantime. Im just removing the framedecoder from the pipeline when i received the whole header of a request/reponse and add a [FixedLengthFrameDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/FixedLengthFrameDecoder.html), as follows the decoder doesnt split every line break, it splits now when the amount of bytes with the length of the new framedecoder is received.

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to go about it, if you are transmitting binary. If you are transmitting strings then NUL is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Hi is there any significance to the size 8192? I've seen that in a couple of places but couldn't understand why.

Comment: 8kb or data, i dont remember it having any significance other than to prevent a denial attack where someone sends you a ton of data. Maybe I am not remembering well enough..:)